# Node.js application deployed on Heroku infinitely loading?

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, deployment

I deploy my Angular application to Heroku, with Node.js as the backend. However, when I deploy to Heroku, the static files page works fine. The page that needs data from backend is infinitely loading. 
This is my Github link: https://github.com/JNUGroup/COVID-19_heroku

**my** `index.js` **as the server file like this:**

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/covid19-tracker'));

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/covid19-tracker/index.html'));
});

app.set('port',port);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port:${port}`);
});
```

**my** `package.json` **look like this:**

```
{
  "name": "covid19-tracker",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"

  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "locutus": "^2.0.11",
    "mocha": "^7.1.2",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.5.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.0.4",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "novelcovid": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1",
    "npm": "6.13.4"
  }
}
```

and all the build is successful. It just cannot read data from backend. I cannot figure it out, hope anyone could give me some suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried checking the log file and see what is happening?

Comment: Use `heroku logs -a` to see the log files.

Comment: thanks, you are right. It's something wrong with my production command and I am trying to fix it.

Comment: I fix the production deploy problem, but it still loading all the time, cannot get backend data. I am confused.